# Pass a value to java class using popupWindow in <a href>

Tags: javascript, jsp

In the jsp, I have something like this:

```
<form id="updateform" name="updateform" method="post">
    <a href="javascript:changePassword()" ><b>change Password</b></font></a>
</form>

function changePassword()
{
    var urlString= "./WebApp?app=msgsrv&class=changepassword&id=" + <%=id%> ;
    popupWindow( urlString , 'ChangePassword', '600', '400', false, true);
}
```

`changePassword` is kind of servlet class, having
`execute(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` method.

This is how my current code looks, but I wanted to get rid of **`id`** in Url due to security issue.

I tried to use both a hidden field and `request.setAttribute()`, and neither of them worked. I wanted to know if there is any other way we could pass a value to the Java class without a form submission as I'm using `popupWindow` in anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not get `java` values in `JavaScript` with anchor tag. The best way is path `id` as method parameter.

```
<form id="updateform" name="updateform" method="post">
            <a href="#" onclick="changePassword(<%=id%>);" ><b>change Password</b></font></a>
</form>

function changePassword(id)
{
    var urlString = "./WebApp?app=msgsrv&class=changepassword&id=" + id + "";
    popupWindow(urlString, 'ChangePassword', '600', '400', false, true);
}
```

Comment: I think the idea here is to generate the url depending on a value from Session or anything. Meaning that that he url is static for the client.

Comment: @AxelH thanks for your comment. May be your opinion is true but I understand he want to pass parameter to javascript with anchor tag and excetly he want to pass parameter to javascript method.

Comment: The problem is `I wanted to get rid of id in Url due to security issue`. So moving the jsp tags from the string to a parameter doesn't change anything... that's purely a design choice...

Comment: @AxelH, can you use anchor tag in javascript? I think problem is that. Anyway we can wait for angela's reply :)

Comment: But once you are running your javascript, there is no more tags... the value of `id` of the server as already been set. Meaning that the string looks like `'./WebApp?app=msgsrv&class=changepassword&id=an_id_that_I_dont_know"'. Same as your onClick block that will have the same `an_id_that_I_dont_know` value as parameter...

Comment: @Afsun Khammadli ,as I mentioned I wanted to take out the Id from Url and pass it over to java class in some other way.

Comment: You can pass by session or cookie. But it is not a statement for using session or cookie.

Comment: @AxelH your opinion is true. I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

I have copeid your statement here.

> I wanted to know if there is any other way we could pass a value to the Java class without a form submission as I'm using popupWindow in anchor tag.

I think you are assuming you can't submit a form due to a tag.But the truth is  you can submit form using anchor tag using javascript.

```
$("form").submit();
```

Full code example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
    $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
        $("form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form id="updateform" name="updateform" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="app" value="msgsrv">
   <input type="hidden" name="class" value="changepassword">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1000">
   <a id="submitbutton" ><b>change Password</b></font></a>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Also you can use AJAX form submission.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:  '<c:url value="/WebApp" />',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    data: jQuery('#updateform').serialize(),
    success: yourSuccessFunctionNameHere
});
```